# Python Pandas: Number of times the same value appears in different columns within the same row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a wide dataset and am trying to figure out how many times the value in column `2019_5` appears for that same member and whether it's continuous or not. The best I've managed to come up with is `dataframe['number_yrs'] = 5 - dataframe.isnull().sum(axis=1)` which gives the following. The problem is that it just looks at whether there is or isn't a NaN, not whether the value is equal to `2019_5`

```
  member  2015_5  2016_5  2017_5  2018_5  2019_5  number_yrs
0    aaa     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      12           1
1    bbb     7.0     7.0     7.0     7.0       7           5
2    ccc    10.0    10.0     NaN     NaN      10           3
3    ddd    12.0     NaN     NaN     7.0       7           3
4    eee    12.0     NaN    10.0     NaN      10           3
```

What I want is for it to be `2` for member `ddd` and `2` for member `eee`

I'd also like to add a `continuous` column that is y/n and indicates whether `number_yrs` is continuous. I expect it would look something like this when all is said and done (correctly)

```
  member  number_yrs continuous
0    aaa           1          n
1    bbb           5          y
2    ccc           3          n
3    ddd           2          y
4    eee           2          n
```

Comment: hi, what defines continuity exactly?

Comment: Why are rows 3 and 4 2 instead of 3?

Comment: @HenryEcker because there are two 7s and two 10s in those rows respectively, i guess

Comment: I see. comparison to 2019_5 only. So then just the y for 3 is unclear?

Comment: yes, not sure how they define whether a row is "continuous" or not `:)`

Comment: I think a row is continuous, when there is no NaN between 2019_5 and the previous value/values.

Comment: @pzmn correct! The anchor value in all cases is 2019_5. For continuous 3 is y because the value in 2018_5 equals the value in 2019_5

MustafaAydın also correct! Again, 2019_5 is the anchor value. I only want to know how many times that value appears in the row, don't care about values that dont equal it

Y'all read my mind better than I could!

Comment: @bb88 Oh, thanks for the clarifications! I also wrote an answer below based on your comment, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df["number_yrs"] = df.filter(regex="_5$").apply(
    lambda x: x.eq(x["2019_5"]).sum(), axis=1
)
df["continuous"] = np.where(
    df.filter(regex="_5$").apply(
        lambda x: sorted(m := x.eq(x["2019_5"])) == m.tolist() and m.sum() > 1,
        axis=1,
    ),
    "y",
    "n",
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  member  2015_5  2016_5  2017_5  2018_5  2019_5  number_yrs continuous
0    aaa     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      12           1          n
1    bbb     7.0     7.0     7.0     7.0       7           5          y
2    ccc    10.0    10.0     NaN     NaN      10           3          n
3    ddd    12.0     NaN     NaN     7.0       7           2          y
4    eee    12.0     NaN    10.0     NaN      10           2          n
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `number_yrs`, you can compare the `2019_5` column against the whole dataframe (but transposed to assure alignment since the latter will be a series):

```
# keep `member` column aside from calculations
>>> df = df.set_index("member")
>>> df.T == df["2019_5"]

member    aaa   bbb    ccc    ddd    eee
2015_5  False  True   True  False  False
2016_5  False  True   True  False  False
2017_5  False  True  False  False   True
2018_5  False  True  False   True  False
2019_5   True  True   True   True   True
```

As you can see, this returns a boolean frame where each entry is marked whether they are equal to `2019_5`'s value per row (and last row is full `True`s as expected). Now we can sum the `True`s per `member` to get `number_yrs`:

```
>>> (df.T == df["2019_5"]).sum(axis=0)

member
aaa    1
bbb    5
ccc    3
ddd    2
eee    2
```

As for the continutiy, we can look at `2018_5`s value and see if it's the same as that of `2019_5` for each row:

```
>>> df["2018_5"] == df["2019_5"]

member
aaa    False
bbb     True
ccc    False
ddd     True
eee    False
```

We're almost there; we can map `True`/`False` values to `"y"`/`"n"` with `map`:

```
>>> (df["2018_5"] == df["2019_5"]).map({True: "y", False: "n"})

member
aaa    n
bbb    y
ccc    n
ddd    y
eee    n
```

So we have the needed new columns. Putting together and assigning those to the dataframe:

```
df["number_yrs"] = (df.T == df["2019_5"]).sum(axis=0)
df["continuous"] = (df["2018_5"] == df["2019_5"]).map({True: "y", False: "n"})
```

gives

```
>>> df

        2015_5  2016_5  2017_5  2018_5  2019_5  number_yrs continuous
member
aaa        NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      12           1          n
bbb        7.0     7.0     7.0     7.0       7           5          y
ccc       10.0    10.0     NaN     NaN      10           3          n
ddd       12.0     NaN     NaN     7.0       7           2          y
eee       12.0     NaN    10.0     NaN      10           2          n
```